# how to reverse query for django_filters fields

Tags: django, django-filters

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    .
    .
    pass


class Color(models.Model):
    color_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')


class ProductColor(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey('Color', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

filters.py

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
           model = Product
           fields = ['color',]
```

i want to filter product by color using django_filters how should i do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new filter to your `filters.py` file, but instead refer to the `ProductColor` model.

**filters.py**

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    productcolor__color__color = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    productcolor__color__color_name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

Note that I'm using `productcolor__color__color` to refer to the `color` property in the `Color` model. The double underscore access a ForeignKey property.

The `lookup_expr='iexact'` will match both lowercase and uppercase color code (**#fff*** or **#FFF**).

Then a simple HTML to filter your queryset could be:

```
<form method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<ul>
    {% for product in filter.qs %}
        <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The `{{ product.name }}` is just an example, I don't know if your `Product` model have a `name` field. But you can access your product following the `{{ product.<field_name> }}`.

You can read more about **django_filters** here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html

Comment: thanks.but a product can have many colors. this way show repetitive product.

Comment: Instead of creating a filter for `ProductColor`, try to create it for `Product`. Then in the field you could try this: `productcolor__color__color = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your view, you can make a query like this

```
c = Color('my desired color', '#ffffff')
result = ProductColor.objects.filter(color=c.color)
for r in result:
   # do something ...
```